# what's the meaning of"to be a best approximate"?

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of"to be a best approximate"?

e.g.
 the coincidence of state and nation **is a best approximate**, and **nowhere more approximate than at their edges**, where the offi cial presumption is quite the opposite—one of sharp distinctions with neighboring nations and states.

Comment: Do you mean _at best approximate_?

Comment: Your source seems to have a typo; it should be *is **at best** approximate...*.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of that is nothing because it's grammatically wrong. As others mentioned in the comments, you need to replace *a* with *at* to make the sentence meaningful.